# The Definition of "Approach infinity at rate n"?

Tags: survival

In p.62 of the textbook, 
"Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data" second edition, 
(Jerald F. Lawless, Wiley, 2003) 
it states

> "An added requirement is that the sequence of fixed censoring time $C_1,\ldots,C_n$" 
>   satisfy conditions so that as $n\to\infty$, the expected information $\mathcal{I}(\theta)$ increases at rate n......the expected number of observed lifetimes approaches infinity at rate n as $n\to\infty$"

For the definition of "rate n", which books or research articles should I read in order to understand it?

Comment: A search of the book on Amazon turns up exactly one use of the phrase "rate $n$", suggesting it is *not* defined anywhere and is merely used in an informal discussion. It could actually mean half a dozen things, including $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{I}_n(\theta)/n = 1$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{I}_n(\theta)/n\lt\infty$, and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{I}_n(\theta)/n \gt 0$. The context suggests something like the latter. For more information, consult [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy. It means that as $n$ grows and grows, at all times $n$ the information in the data $C_1, \dots, c_n$ should be approximately proportional to $n$. In the lifetimes example this means that, if for instance the distribution of censoring times is stationary, then, if the lifetimes intends to increase with time, more and more lifetimes will be censored, so the condition is not fulfilled.

If both the distribution of lifetimes and the distribution of censoring times are stationary, then the condition will typically be fulfilled.